# How can I join conditions of one line with samples of another in pandas/python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

There is a software that exports a table as the follow example:

```
import pandas as pd

s0 = ',,,,Cond1,,,,Cond2,,'.split(',')
s1 = 'Gene name,Description,Anova,FoldChange,Sample1,Sample2,Sample3,Sample4,Sample5,Sample6,Sample7'.split(',')
s2 = 'HK1,Hexokinase,0.05,1.00,1.5,1.0,0.5,1.0,0,0,0'.split(',')

df= pd.DataFrame( data= (s0, s1, s2))
```

---

```
           0            1      2           3        4        5        6  \
0                                               Cond1                     
1  Gene name  Description  Anova  FoldChange  Sample1  Sample2  Sample3   
2        HK1   Hexokinase   0.05        1.00      1.5      1.0      0.5   

         7        8        9       10  
0             Cond2                    
1  Sample4  Sample5  Sample6  Sample7  
2      1.0        0        0        0  
H
```

owever, the organization of this table is not straightforward and, therefore, is hard to analyze the conditions.

I would like to produce data frames, which the conditions are matched with it respectively sample.

It should be something like the output of the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

s1 = 'Gene name,Description,Anova,FoldChange,Sample1.Cond1,Sample2.Cond1,Sample3.Cond1,Sample4.Cond1,Sample5.Cond2,Sample6.Cond2,Sample7.Cond2'.split(',')
s2 = 'HK1,Hexokinase,0.05,1.00,1.5,1.0,0.5,1.0,0,0,0'.split(',')

df= pd.DataFrame(data= (s1, s2))
```

---

```
           0            1      2           3              4              5  \
0  Gene name  Description  Anova  FoldChange  Sample1.Cond1  Sample2.Cond1   
1        HK1   Hexokinase   0.05        1.00            1.5            1.0   

               6              7              8              9             10  
0  Sample3.Cond1  Sample4.Cond1  Sample5.Cond2  Sample6.Cond2  Sample7.Cond2  
1            0.5            1.0              0              0              0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter `NaN` Values ​​in `row 0` with [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html). Then fill them with [`Series.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html).
 Finally, you can use [`Series.str.cat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html) to join both rows:

```
df.iloc[0]=  df.iloc[1].str.cat( df.iloc[0]
               .where(df.iloc[0].notnull() & df.iloc[0].ne(''))
               .ffill(),'.' ).fillna(df.iloc[1])

df=df.drop(1).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
           0            1      2           3              4              5  \
0  Gene name  Description  Anova  FoldChange  Sample1.Cond1  Sample2.Cond1   
1        HK1   Hexokinase   0.05        1.00            1.5            1.0   

               6              7              8              9             10  
0  Sample3.Cond1  Sample4.Cond1  Sample5.Cond2  Sample6.Cond2  Sample7.Cond2  
1            0.5            1.0              0              0              0
```